# References for Neumann eigenfunctions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for references on eigenfunctions with Neumann boundary condition.

In an article, the author wrote in introduction that when a domain is planar polygon, the second eigenfunctions on it have critical points at vertices. But, I could not find the source. I think this is probably a well-known fact. But I am very interested in the proof.

It may be a famous fact for experts, but I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: This is quite straightforward once we know that the gradient is well-defined and continuous. Indeed: by the Neumann boundary condition, the gradient of an eigenfunction at a boundary point is parallel to the boundary. Therefore, at a vertex, the gradient is parallel to two different directions, and hence it is necessarily zero.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you very much for your comments. I am convinced. I didn't think of it until you said. The comments of Carlo Beenakker is in a different direction, right?

Comment: I think so, it deals with non-vertex critical points. Still, it is an excellent answer!

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I think so too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01800) I would conclude the statement is false: the second Neumann eigenfunction of an acute triangle has one non-vertex critical point.

This was a [Polymath problem.](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=The_hot_spots_conjecture)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mean that the second Neumann eigenfunction on an acute triangle does not have critical points at vertices?

Comment: that is not how I understand the cited paper: the statement is that there is exactly one critical point that is not at a vertex, I don't think critical points at vertices are excluded.